# How to do android scale animation based on view's position on screen and focus that view in centre?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, zooming, scaling

I want animation like this: [Calendar Animation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/172dtGoNQ3xbDMogTPvqlfvPTB2Ur2H6V/view)

I want to scale animation on calendar and focus on current date to centre.
I am new in android animation, I do some stuff for scaling:

**zoom_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">
<scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="2"
    android:toYScale="2" />
</set>
```

but using this, it scaling the calendar to centre but I want the current date in centre.
Anybody have an idea how to do this whole animation? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to get position of the view/content that you want to be in center, because you need to do some translation

here example zoom to center of TextView with random position inside a ConstraintView

to zoom in to the specific position you need to translate view so the point is in the center, you can do it by change the difX and difY formula

```
float layoutWitdh = layout.getWidth();
        float layoutHeight = layout.getHeight();

        float x = view.getX();
        float y = view.getY();
        float w = view.getWidth();
        float h = view.getHeight();

        float difX = (layoutWitdh - w) / 2 - x;
        float difY = (layoutHeight - h) / 2 - y;

        view.animate().translationX(difX).translationY(difY).scaleY(5).scaleX(5).setDuration(1000);
```

[image]

edit:

check this project https://github.com/aiwiguna/AndroidZoom

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replay, by following your code I am getting this as result: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UpEajxSyAqtw4hNk16LlTUve3QNo-1JY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I want to zoom current date in centre, I have replaced layout with my LinearLayout and view with my current date's textview of the calendar.

Comment: you need to get x y position of the current date, I cannot reproduce your calendar, so I give the general direction how to zoom in

Comment: can you please tell me that how can I get x y position of current date with an example!!

Comment: like I said before I cannot reproduce your calendar because I didn't know how you show your calendar, using library or you create your self

Comment: I am using this library for calendar : https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView

Comment: You are awesome!! I implemented it and it's working fine. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad to help, i didnt even know why you ask my help in a ios post lol